# How to access a value in the database using Dart?

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I put a document from firestore database inside a key named "product", which is the following:
`{"wallname":"","height":0,"width":0,"wallcondition":0,"**product"**:null,"color":null,"area":0,"hoursrequired":0,"laborprice":0}`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxmIi.png)

I already have the whole DB document inside my key,

Now I want to access the values which is called image_product (value in the database);
Later I want to access the subcollections as well. Anyone could help me out? Thanks a lot!

var document = data[index]["product"]; //here the doc from DB goes
var image = document["image_product"]; //here I should be able to access it but I couldn't
return image;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the values from a document in firestore you can do this:

```
final docSnapshot = await firestore.collection('you collection name')
    .doc('your document id').get();  
Map<String, dynamic> data = docSnapshot.data()!;

final fieldToAccess = data['fieldName'];
return fieldToAccess;
```

If you want to access to a subcollection you should repeat this code but adding the subcollection like this:

```
final docSnapshot = await firestore.collection('your collection name')
    .doc('your doc id').collection('your subcollection name').doc('your other doc id').get();
```

In firestore when you access a document in a collection you don't access their subcollections. So if you want to get the data from the subcollection you have to do another operation.

Comment: It did not work, cause the documentReference is already assined to my key "product", it is missing probably one line of code, I tought it could work as well:

'String? getWallProductCopy(
  List<dynamic> data,
  int index,
) {
    return data[index]['product']['image_product'];
}'
the 'data[index]['product']' I have the whole document, Now I want to read the value ["image_product"]

Comment: if product is you document reference try doing a `snapshot= await product().get` remember that you have to return a Future. So if you want to return a String you have to declare your method as `Future<String>` and then try to return `snapshot.data["image_product"]`

Comment: could you help me on discord? If you wanna charge me, how much  would that be?

Comment: Right now I am busy. But if you want to post more code there then sure

Comment: perfect add me on there viniceciliato#2841